# Не подгружаются стили и скрипты

Tags: php, wordpress

Добавил код в *functions.php*:

```
function theme_name_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style('style_blog', get_template_directory_uri() . "/css/style_blog.css");
    wp_register_script('jone', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/site.js');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_name_scripts');
```

Но ничего не подгружается. Также не подгружаются стили плагина *Visual Composer*. Тему делаю с нуля.

Answer (score 2):

1) Скрипт мало зарегистрировать, его надо еще объявить

2) [параметр `$deps`](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC/wp_enqueue_style#.D0.9F.D0.B0.D1.80.D0.B0.D0.BC.D0.B5.D1.82.D1.80.D1.8B)

Итого:

```
function theme_name_scripts() {
   wp_enqueue_style( 'style_blog', get_template_directory_uri() . "/css/style_blog.css", false );

   wp_register_script( 'jone', get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/site.js', false );
   wp_enqueue_script( 'jone');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_name_scripts' );
```

Comment: Не помогло. Я смотрю через исходный код, но там ничего не добавляется.

Comment: `<?php wp_head(); ?>` в `header.php` и `<? wp_footer(); ?>` в `footer.php` присутствуют?

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему. Не написал в *header.php* функцию `wp_head()`.